# Release allocated or initialized object in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Memory management says we must `release` an object created with `alloc`. Consider this typical example code.

```
XYZClass *obj = [[XYZClass alloc] init];
// use obj
[obj release];
```

But in this example, `obj` may not be the object returned from `alloc`, as Apple's documentation says

> Note: It’s possible for init to return a different object than was created by alloc, so it’s best practice to nest the calls as shown.

So this typical example seems to release the object returned from `init`, breaking memory management rules, and not release the object returned from `alloc`, further breaking the rules.
How is this typical example valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you code uses manual memory management, that is something I would not recommend, since Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS we have support for Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is a compiler feature that provides automatic memory management of Objective-C objects. See [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) :

> Instead of your having to remember when to use retain, release, and
> autorelease, ARC evaluates the lifetime requirements of your objects
> and automatically inserts appropriate memory management calls for you
> at compile time. The compiler also generates appropriate dealloc
> methods for you.

With regards to your specific question, the fact that *init* might return a different object does not break the memory management, because that different object will use the same allocation. This is quite common for class clusters that the initializer might return a internal subclass.

Comment: Ok, so then I guess for an object you create, the policy is not in fact to release the object, but to release any object with the same allocation.